# Making get feature request to forget between clicks in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I currently have a map with projects on it that when you click on it, it returns the information of said project using the code below.

The issue I'm having is that every so often it will duplicate the responses it is returning. It's almost as though it's remembering that it's been previously clicked on and then adding another response on top of it. How can I make it stop doing this?

```
  function projectName(browserEvent) {
    var coordinate = browserEvent.coordinate;
    var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);
    var el = document.getElementById('projectNumber');
    el.innerHTML = '';
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
      el.innerHTML += feature.get('Proj_Number') + '<br>';
      return true;
    });
  }
  map.on('pointerdown', projectName);
```

Edit: Tried testing this without the + in the += feature.get but it only returned one result when there are multiple points in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Just try changing to:

```
map.on('singleclick', projectName);
```

[Reference](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html#event:singleclick)

Comment: Afraid this hasn't worked, it still creates a duplicate of the records it brings back when i click off "site 1", click onto "site 2" and then click back onto "site 1".

Comment: Try change the increment `el.innerHTML +=` to `el.innerHTML =` since the truthy return stop the interation.

Comment: Thanks, the only issue with that is I have multiple points at the same place so it only returns the first one of these and not any others that may be behind.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/CuDYJe/preview) can help you, it's an overlapping test.

Comment: Really nice idea, the only issue i see with that is that i have a lot (thousands) of points and that could become cluttered very quickly, i might try a version of that which closes after the mouseover function.

Comment: The other issue with that @Jonatas Walker is that I want the user to click on one point and it then shows all of the information for that exact spot in one go. Any other ideas? Cheers

Comment: I don't see the difficulty. Somehow you have to show them individually and then (onclick) show the info stored. Maybe you create a plunker|jsfiddle.